# Download grandes com QNetworkreply::readAll congelam por alguns segundos

Tags: c++, qt

Ao usar `QNetworkreply::readAll` para gravar os dados em um `QFile`, no momento que o download chega no final ocorre um rápido congelamento de 2 a 4 segundos e também varia conforme a rede ou site que estou baixando, logo após volta ao normal e o download termina.

Me parece que o buffer lido aumenta mais que o normal no final

Segue um exemplo de código:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("C:/exemplo/bigfile.7z");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        return 1;
    }

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://localhost/bigfile.7z"));

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, [&](){
        QTime time;
        time.start();

        QByteArray ba = reply->readAll();
        file.write(ba);

        int duration= time.elapsed();

        qDebug() << "read" << ba.size() << " bytes of data. (" << duration << " msecs)";
    });

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&](){
        qDebug() << "finished!";
        a.quit();
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Este problema ocorre quando tento baixar arquivos grandes como 300mb por exemplo, veja o resultado:

[image: resultado]

Note que no final do download (praticamente no 99%) o `reply->readAll` e `write`, leva 1617msecs e depois 2741msecs, ou seja praticamente 4 segundos, veja que o `readAll` nas duas ultimas chamadas retornaram bem mais dados.

Isto causa um pequeno travamento em aplicativos interface gráfica (que usam `QWidget`).

Comment: Guilherme pelo que percebi vc esta conectando os eventos após a realização do chamado do get e eles estão referenciando o reply e não o manager, provavelmente por isso eles não estão sendo disparados. Tente coloca-los antes do get e ao manager.

Comment: O exemplo da documentão deles funciona certinho Guilherme, veja por exemplo essa implementação de download disponível: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php

Comment: Guilherme, você não postou um [mcve] então não dá pra ter certeza, mas talvez o problema seja o fato de que você não conecta ao `finished` e não fecha o arquivo no final. Eu acabei de fazer um teste (com um exemplo que eu mesmo criei aqui seguindo o que vc descreveu fazer) e funcionou perfeitamente com um arquivo (de vídeo) com mais de 700mb.

Comment: O código do meu exemplo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93473897/codigo.zip

Comment: To saindo agora, mas vejo depois. Dá uma testada com o meu código. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Obrigado, vou ver o seu código ;)

Comment: Eu ia comentar que rodei o seu código aqui (com o mesmo vídeo que eu usei nos meus testes) e não tive problema algum. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira parece que o problema varia conforme a REDE que estou baixando, no caso quase todos sites que rodei não tive problema algum, todavia o site da empresa aonde trabalho geram downloads dinamicos as vezes causa isto e a um arquivo estático em `http://localhost` sempre causam isto, pode ser a rede que tenta acelerar o processo de entrega, limitar o buffer de leitura parece que resolveu :)

Comment: Ah, bom saber então que limitar o buffer utilizado pode ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu notei que `readyRead` fica alto apenas no final, talvez seja a aplicação ou a rede que tenta adiantar o processo de download, isto varia de rede para rede e conforme a velocidade da mesma, ou seja o problema pode ocorrer uma hora e outra não.

Em aplicações GUI é este tempo de gravação longo que causa a sensação de "travamento" por ~4 segundos.

O que resolveu foi limitar `buffer`, para isto eu usei [`QNetworkReply::setReadBufferSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#setReadBufferSize), veja diferença do resultado:

[image: com setReadBufferSize]

A leitura não passou de 1048576 bytes, o que levou entre 2 e 10 msecs para gravar, ou seja não gastou nem meio segundo.